# convert table into comma separated in text file using bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file like this:

```
+------------------+------------+----------+
|     col_name     | data_type  | comment  |
+------------------+------------+----------+
| _id              | bigint     |          |
| starttime        | string     |          |
+------------------+------------+----------+
```

how can i get a result like this using bash

```
(_id bigint, starttime string   )
```

so just the column names and type

```
#remove first 3 lines 
sed -e '1,3d' < columnnames.txt >clean.txt

#remove first character from each line
sed 's/^.//'  < clean.txt >clean.txt

#remove last character from each line
sed 's/.$//' < clean.txt >clean.txt


# remove certain characters 
sed 's/[+-|]//g' < clean.txt >clean.txt 

# remove last line 
sed  '$ d' < clean.txt >clean.txt
```

so this is what i have so far, if there is a better implementation let me know!

Comment: I'd use perl or python or something, not shell.

Comment: Just a remark: You can use `sed -i … clean.txt` to modify the file in place instead of using `< clean.txt > clean.txt`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the tool which outputs this table, I suppose it's a database client, supports machine readable output like cvs as well. Check the manual of that program

Comment: Is this `mysql` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar, using only `awk`:

```
awk -F ' *[|]' 'BEGIN {printf("(")} NR>3 && NF>1 {printf("%s%s%s", NR>4 ? "," : "", $2, $3)} END {printf(" )\n")}' columnnames.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Set the field separator to vertical bar surrounded by any number of spaces.
# BEGIN and END blocks print the opening and closing parens
# The line between skips the header lines and any line starting with '+'

$ awk -F"[[:space:]]*[|][[[:space:]]*" '
    BEGIN { printf "%s", "( "}  
    NR > 3 && $0 !~ /^[+]/ { printf("%s%s %s", c, $2, $3); c = ", " } 
    END { print " )" }' file

( _id bigint, starttime string )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[| ]+' 'NR>3 && NF>1{v=v s $2" "$3; s=", "} END{print "("v")"}' file
(_id bigint, starttime string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this :

```
cat input.txt \
| tail -n +4 \
| awk -F'[^a-zA-Z_]+' '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf $i" " }}'
```

Its a little bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to implement [Diego Torres Milano's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60010226/7939871) as a stand-alone awk program:

`tableconvert`

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS="[[:space:]]*[|][[[:space:]]*"
  printf "%s", "( "
}

{
  if (FNR <= 3 || match($0, /^[+]/))
    next
  else {
    printf("%s%s %s", c, $2, $3)
    c = ", "
  }
} 

END {
  print " )" 
}
```

Make `tableconvert` an executable:

```sh
chmod +x tableconvert
```

Run `tableconvert` on `intablefile.txt`

```sh
./tableconvert intablefile.txt 
( _id bigint, starttime string )
```

With added bonus that using `FNR` instead of `NR` allow the awk program to process multiple input files as arguments:

```sh
./tableconvert infille1.txt infile2.txt infile3.txt ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the other answers using `awk` with the *field-separator* being the `'|'` with optional spaces on either side as GNU `awk` allows, then taking fields `2` and `3` as the fields wanted in each record, and formatting the output as described in the question with the closing `"  )"` provided in the `END` rule:

```
$ awk -F' *\\| *' '
    NR>3 && $1~/^[+]/{exit}                 # exit condition first line w/^+
    NR==4{$1=$1; printf "(%s %s", $2,$3}    # 1st data record is 4
    NR>4{$1=$1; printf ", %s %s", $2,$3}    # process all remainng records
    END{print "  )"}                        # output closing "  )"
' table
(_id bigint, starttime string  )
```

(**note:** if you don't want the two-spaces before the closing `")"`, just remove them from the `print` in the `END` rule)

Rather than using a `BEGIN` the first record of interest (`4`) is used to provide the opening `"("`. Look things over and let me know if you have questions.